# How to do a date range entityQuery with a Date only field in Drupal 8?

Tags: 8, database

In Drupal 8, the **Date only** field stores data in a **varchar** column in a **CCYY-MM-DD** format, e.g., **2016-04-18**.

As such, you can't simply do a greater than (**>=**), less than (**<=**) or similar timestamp based entityQuery anymore.

Is there a simple solution on how to deal with this? Specifically I am attempting to do two queries, one where the date field is between 14 and 21 days old, and one where the date field is 21 and over days old.

Comment: Doesn't `>=` work? 20160318 >= 20160218

Comment: The data is stored as `XXXX-XX-XX` (2016-04-18), so it's technically not a number, therefore doing a numerical condition against it wouldn't be valid.

Comment: `'2016-04-18' > '2016-03-18'` works for me, and `'2014-04-18' > '2018-02-01'` returns `FALSE`. Yes, it's a string comparison, but given the string format, it should work. After all, `'1' < '2'`.

Comment: The problem would be with `'0001' < '2'`, maybe.

Answer (score 25):

I'm doing lots of conditions like that in entity queries, I haven't encountered a problem yet.

The main thing you have to be aware of is the timezone the data is stored, which is UTC. You need to convert it to the storage timezone (there's a constant for that), or your query will be off by a few hours.

Here's an example based on something I'm doing, if you only store days, then there is a constant for formatting that too.

```
$date = new DrupalDateTime('21 days ago');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DATETIME_STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
$formatted = $date->format(DATETIME_DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);

$nids = \Drupal::entityQuery('node')
  ->condition('your_date_field.value', $formatted, '<=')
  ->range(0, 50)
  ->execute();
```

As of **Drupal 8.5** [change](https://www.drupal.org/node/2912980) one should use following to get formatted date

```
use Drupal\Core\Datetime\DrupalDateTime;
use Drupal\datetime\Plugin\Field\FieldType\DateTimeItemInterface;
```

```
$date = new DrupalDateTime('21 days ago');
$date->setTimezone(new \DateTimezone(DateTimeItemInterface::STORAGE_TIMEZONE));
$formatted = $date->format(DateTimeItemInterface::DATETIME_STORAGE_FORMAT);
```

Comment: This worked great for a field with timestamp—in the database the storage was like `2016-07-18T13:00:00`, but Drupal handled the conversion and comparison properly using this setup.

Comment: This didn't work for me using the `created` field, but just passing in the timestamp returned by `$node->getCreatedTime()` did (Drupal 8.8.x).

Comment: This still works in Drupal 9.5