# Complex where condition with entity field query (D8)

Tags: 8, entities, database

Is there a method similar to the [D7 dynamic query where method](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/api/database-api/dynamic-queries/conditional-clauses) to allow us to use arbitrary snippets of SQL to restrict the result set?

Take the following MYSQL query as an example:

```
SELECT id, publish_date
FROM teaching_period
WHERE publish_date IS NULL OR UNIX_TIMESTAMP(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(publish_date, ' 23:59:59'), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i:%s')) > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
ORDER BY created DESC
LIMIT 0, 1
```

How can I create the where statement in this query using the D8 entity query API? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, in general, it is not. Entity query is *not* an SQL-query replacement, it designed to also work with other storage backends, so you can not use 100% of the SQL features.

If you need that, you have to implement your own SQL query.

That said, I don't quite understand why your special SQL logic is even necessary, date fields can be queried natively, e.g. publish_date > :date should just work, as long as you provide the date in the correct format as and timezone input.

See [How to do a date range entityQuery with a Date only field in Drupal 8?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/198324/how-to-do-a-date-range-entityquery-with-a-date-only-field-in-drupal-8)

Comment: Thanks for the link - that looks like a much better solution (especially with the timezone consideration)